# How to receive the embeddable object on id if in the class there is no such field?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am newbie in spring-data-jpa.
The class Person contains the field Set<'Address> addresses. When I save object person with related addresses to data base I use join for addresses on person_id: joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"). Class Address doesn't have field id or person_id. Data saved correctly. How to write method in AddressRepository to get Address from db by using person_id?

class Person:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByPhone",
        query = "select p from Person as p join p.phoneNumbers as pn where pn.number = :number")
@Table(uniqueConstraints={
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"lastName", "firstName", "patronymic"})
})
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    private String patronymic;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "person_phone_numbers", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"))
    private Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new HashSet<>();

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "person_addresses", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"))
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "addressLine1", column = @Column(name = "house_number")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "addressLine2", column = @Column(name = "street"))
    })
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String lastName, String firstName, String patronymic,
                  Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers, Set<Address> addresses) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
        this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
        this.addresses = addresses;

    }
getters and setters
}
```

---

class Address

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String addressLine1;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String addressLine2;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String city;

    @NotNull
    @Size
    private String region;

    @NotNull
    @Size
    private String country;

    @NotNull
    @Size
    private String zipCode;

    public Address() {
    }

    public Address(@NotNull @Size(max = 100) String addressLine1, @NotNull @Size(max = 100) String addressLine2,
                   @NotNull @Size(max = 100) String city, @NotNull @Size String region,
                   @NotNull @Size String country, @NotNull @Size String zipCode) {
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
        this.city = city;
        this.region = region;
        this.country = country;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }
getters and setters
}
```

---

interface AddressRepository (it give me an error org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter'):

```
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> {

   Address findByPersonId(Integer person_id);
}
```

Comment: I dont think you can do it in AddressRepository. Since there is no reference to Person inside Address Entity. But you can do it the other way. I mean you can search from PersonRepository

Comment: You have a **set** of `Address`es in `Person` but want to get **one** `Address` by the person's ID - what do you mean?? Or maybe you still need a set of addresses?...

Comment: I realized my mistake.